# PostgreSQL and MySQL with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

I was able to create my first App with Django using the default SQLite3. I am now checking some tutorials on how to install MySQL and PostgreSQL and connect it to Django so I can develop a more advanced application. The only thing I cannot understand, is the Models.py will still the same in term of syntax? I mean the syntax in creating a table in MySQL is different on how we create a table in Models.py. I mean, I need some clarification please in this matter. Thank you.

Comment: Well that's the point of the ORM: abstracting away the details of the underlying database. I am not very familiar with django but I guess you somehow specify the database engine you want to use and your models will stay the same.

Comment: You should go through the django tutorial on the django site to understand ORM and how it relates to which database you select

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as karlson says in the comments, django abstracts your models away from the database engine, so by changing [your settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#engine), you are changing the database backend that is used which handles the conversion from the model fields to the database field types